# If they hadn't eaten the fruit

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, messiah, adam

I recall hearing (many years ago) a medrash that said that if Adam and Chava had not eaten of the Eitz Hada'at, and made it to Shabbat, Mashiach would have come. I have been unable to find it. I was told to look in the Ohr Hachaim in Bereisheet but the nearest I found (so far) [is](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.3.19.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> Had he not sinned, the holiness acquired by triumphing over temptation would have guaranteed that he did not have to return to his lowly origin. His body would have become so refined that it no longer would have been considered as part of the earth.

Does anyone know the medrash?

Comment: Nitzotzos has a dvar Torah also mentioning this: Had Adam refrained from eating from the Eitz HaDa’as (tree of knowledge) until Shabbos he would have fulfilled his mission and brought the world to its ultimate state of harmony. - I did not find a Midrash, but the Or HaChaim in parashas Vayechi also mentions this.